# How to get right datetime of specific country in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am in need of saving time when user get register. I am trying code in PHP for generating India specific time.

```
 $timezone = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata" );
        $date = new DateTime();
        $date->setTimezone($timezone );
        $dtobj = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $dtobj;
```

it is working but not showing correct time. I am using Godaddy server.
Time given by code is 2014-01-13 10:21:29 but actual time is 2014-01-13 02:20:55. I search on Google and tried almost all function but getting same difference. What should i do for getting exact time.

Comment: Check your server time, I guess this is your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced many time based issues, which have been resolved by modifying the server's php.ini file (hopefully you have access to this?). I found that setting the timezone elsewhere (ie from within a script) proved fruitless.

**To edit your php.ini file:**

1. Find your ini file (typically `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` or similar)
2. Track down the line `;date.timezone =` (typically line 1018)
3. Uncomment the setting (remove the leading `;`)
4. Add your timezone, for example: `date.timezone = Asia/Kolkata`
5. Restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 5):

Using the date_default_timezone_set() function to set a default timezone:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$date = new DateTime('now');
echo 'UTC:     '.$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";

$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Lisbon'));
echo 'Lisbon:  '.$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";

$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
echo 'Kolkata: '.$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";

?>
```

Output:

```
UTC:     2014-04-05 13:45:56
Lisbon:  2014-04-05 14:45:56
Kolkata: 2014-04-05 19:15:56
```